# Unity ScrollRect not scrolling to a value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using two arrow buttons (Up/Down). When pressed, they change the values for scroll rect in the vertical direction.
Problem is, I am manually trying to change the value in my script but it is not changing at all.
How do I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScrollViewSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ScrollRect scrollRect;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scrollRect = GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
        Scroll();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition); //Outputs value as 1
    }

    public void Scroll(){
        StartCoroutine(ResetToMid());
    }

    IEnumerator ResetToMid() {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.5f;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine, just make sure the **Scroll View** is on the right scroll direction (Vertical in your case).

[image]

Second thing is the **Content** GameObject's Rect should be covering the the content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And don't forget to Stop the coroutine, put it in the end of the method ResetToMid(){ ...... ; StopCoroutine(ResetToMid());}